# Remove extra lines in a text file

Tags: java, file, line

I would like to remove an extra line at the front of the text file that's being created for some reason. Here's the code for what I'm doing:

```
String line;
while ((line = textReader.readLine()) != null) {
   if (!line.contains("//")) textData.add(line);
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//.*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
   line = matcher.replaceFirst("");
```

If I remove the if (!line.contains("//")) textData.add(line); then the lines are not being outputted. Here's what I use to invoke writing method:

```
     WriteToFile filetoo = new WriteToFile("/Users/John/Desktop/newtext.txt", true);
            filetoo.write(anyLines[i]);
```

I want to start from the very first line and start writing to the file. Here's what my file looks like:

```
................. // blank space (I want to get rid of this)
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Though I want it to look like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the line is "empty" and skip it - `if (line.trim().length() != 0)` should tell you if the line is not "blank".

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. You could put the if statement above around the part that processes the lines to ensure the line has something in it before processing it. Or you could add the line `if(line.trim().length()==0) continue;` to the beginning of your `while` loop. That will skip any blank line in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

SO it is not a blank line and instead matches the RE /^\s*\/\/.*/?

The RE I quoted should work, of if you are not using the / command, "^\s*//.*"

If it is blank, perhaps something like this:

[edit]

```
first = 1;
while ((line = textReader.readLine()) != null) {
  if (first)
   {
     if (matchera.matches("\s*$", line))
     {
        continue;
     }
     first = 0;
   }
```

Comment: no, it is a blank line - I write to the file and see that the first line is blank. I want to remove the blank line and start at the top.

Comment: I feel bamana's method is much simpler (and works), but thanks anyway.